# Hosting Wordpress behind Nginx in a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am attempting to host a wordpress installation at http://mydomain.com/blogtest and have followed the guide at http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress however I am still getting "No input file specified." for any requests.

Using Nginx 1.2.1 and PHP 5.3.6 with php-fpm

Here is the Nginx config file:

```
upstream wptest {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  access_log logs/access.log;
  error_log logs/error.log;

  location /blogtest {
    access_log logs/blogtest.access.log;
    error_log logs/blogtest.error.log;

    root /opt/myblogwp;

    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blogtest/index.php;

  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blogtest)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass wptest;
  }
}
```

Here is my fastcgi_params file:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

# Next line added by AdamJT for php-fpm
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

#Concrete5 fix by AdamJT
#fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

I have also edited /usr/local/php/lib/php.ini to set cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that `location /blogtest {}` means that your files will be searched under

```
/opt/myblogwp/blogtest
```

Is this the root dir of your wp site? You might need to use `alias` instead of `location`. Alias allows to set virtual dir /somedir/ to have root dir as /opt/someotherdir/.
Also, I'm not quite familiar with `fastcgi_split_path_info`, but it seems like there is something missing there.
Looking at the example:

```
Here's an example. The script show.php receives as argument the string article/0001. The following configuration will handle path splitting properly:

location ~ ^.+\.php {
  (...)
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/php$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
  (...)
}
Requesting /show.php/article/0001 sets SCRIPT_FILENAME to /path/to/php/show.php and PATH_INFO to /article/0001.
```

for your example - I don't see how you set the real PATH_INFO and SCRIPT_FILENAME - you're using the default values... I guess you have to tweak these parameters a bit. The error that you get is `No input file specified`. That means that no script_filename is being passed to PHP. So you should trace and fix the PATH_INFO and SCRIPT_FILENAME, so that at the end you should get something like this:

```
/path/to/wpresssite/index.php$fastcgi_script_name
```

Comment: alias can only be used inside location, not as a replacement to it. I get the same error when I replace root with alias. How do I trace  PATH_INFO and SCRIPT_FILENAME?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with PHP, actually when I need to run a php site, I'm using uwsgi. What FCGI server do you use - what's listening on 127.0.0.1:9000? Try to enable some detailed logs - if you can dump all FCGI params - I guess that'll be enough to find out what the problem is. Also  try to set PATH_INFO to a static path(to point to the WP site), and try tweaking the SCRIPT_FILENAME value.